# Opening javascript links in new tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, tabs

([Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226686/allow-option-for-open-link-in-new-tab-in-javascriptwindow-open), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024390/opening-a-link-in-new-tab) and [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015982/javascript-tweak-to-open-url-either-in-a-new-window-or-new-tab-based-on-users-c) looks how to force users open link in new tab)
But in my situation I visit some sites regularly and they have links like this:

```
<a href='javascript:window.open("/view.php?id=1234","_self")'>Link name</a>
```

This type of link makes me impossible to open link in new tab with a mouse click. Every time I see these links, I duplicate the tab in Chrome and click link inside the cloned tab. And go back to original tab and continue to surf. Is it possible to open these links in new tab with a chrome extension, js code or something?

You can try one of the links here: http://bit.ly/12dUk4V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. . The problem is that these links can be kind of "about:blank" because they are not specified in the `href` attribute normally, so it breaks your expected behavior when using ctrl+click, middle click or something alike. Sometimes sites links to "javascript:" pseudo-protocol, sometimes the link is for "#" with a "onclick" trigger... It depends on the situation.

. . For this specific case it's easy enough to write a user script that will rewrite these kind of links, if you're willing to use something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       SelfLinks Fixer
// @namespace  http://dnun.es./
// @version    0.1
// @description  This script rewrites "window.open(..., '_self')" links so that you can click them as you wish.
// @match      http://libgen.info/*
// @copyright  2013, http://dnun.es.
// ==/UserScript==

var tRegExp = '^javascript: *'+
  '(window\\.)?open\\('+
  ' *(([\'"])([^\\3]+)\\3) *,'+
  ' *[\'"]_self[\'"] *'+
  '\\) *;? *$';
var fixLinksCheck = new RegExp(tRegExp);
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i = 0, n = as.length, a;
for (;i<n;i++) { a = as[i];
  if (fixLinksCheck.test(a.href)) { //damn you _self link!
    a.href = a.href.replace(fixLinksCheck, '$4');
  }
}
```

. . This code "fixes" only the "*_self*" links by changing them to *normal* links. You can then click them with middle button, holding ctrl/shift or whatever. It also leave the "_blank" or "_top" links untouched.

Comment: Comments on your own post are quite useless. You'd better edit your post.

Comment: Sometimes I think some info are not _that_ important and belongs to comments, not the answer. Maybe this was not the case, really. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. All you need is to inject a simple line of JavaScript code in every page. I had done it before in a Firefox extension.

You just need to override window.open method:

```
var open_= window.open;         

window.open = function(url, name, opts) {
   if (name === '_self') { name = '_blank'; }
   open_(url, '_blank', opts);
};
```

Complete code on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dp4Uz/

Comment: You could do `if (name === '_self') { name = '_blank'; }` or something so that it won't mess with other types of window.open links, maybe?